# Correct use of differentiation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a PDE of the form `f = F[x,y,z,u,ux,uy,ux]` where `u = U[x,y,z], ux = D[u,x], uy = D[u,y], uz = D[u,z]`. If I want to differentiate `f` with respect to `ux`, do I use `fux = D[F,ux]`, `D[f,u,x]` or `D[f,x,u]`?

Comment: Note that `ux` is a single variable, and `u x` (**note the space!!!**) is a product of two variables. So, it is *not* true that `F[x, y, z, ux, uy, ux]` has `u` in it.

Comment: Sorry, `f` has `u`. Corrected.

Comment: "differentiate `f` with respect to `ux`" - `D[]` does not accept expressions in its second and succeeding arguments, so why not use the chain rule?